# I purchased a Ubuntu-preinstalled, used, Asus Mini Notebook off of Amazon. I pushed the power button while it was installing updates.

Tags: ubuntu

Okay the subject line basically contains my question. I purchased a **used Ubuntu-preinstalled Asus Mini Notebook computer** off of Amazon. It worked just fine for awhile. Then one day while it was installing updates and I was working on reviewing programming in the C language and learning the Shell at the same, it started going on the fritz. I was installing the updates over a [high speed, 50 mbps but probably 15 mbps in reality, Internet connection] **wireless Internet connection at home**, and I went ahead and pushed the power button (hey, it works with Windows). So, now when I power up what used to be my computer, the log on screen looks completely different as if I installed a whole new operating system or something (but it **is** still Ubuntu, it just looks radically different, but probably like it is supposed to, I guess the updates were just fairly dramatic). Anyway, when I log on the screen just shakes momentarily and takes me back to the same log on screen. I've tried going into the BIOS but there doesn't seem to be anything I can do. Please help.

Answer (score 2):

Given that it is November, about a month after a ubuntu release what it sounds like is that you powered off your machine during a distro upgrade. You were probably moving from 14.04 to 14.10.

1. Power on your computer
2. When you reach the lock screen instead of logging in press `Control + Alt + F1` Your screen should be black with white text and should prompt you to login.
3. After you log in run `sudo apt-get update and && sudo apt-get dist-upgrade` to finish upgrading to ubuntu 14.10
4. When the update finishes reboot by typing the command `sudo reboot`

You will still have the foreign login screen but things should at least be functional. If you really want to roll back the changes there are ways but that will take a lot of fighting, if you want the previous version I would suggest a re-install.

Comment: It was "quite awhile" ago, maybe this Summer, or maybe even prior to that that I did that. I think you're right. It may have been the upgrade to 14.10 or the one prior to that depending on when it was. I'm a complete newbie to Linux, so I'm not sure exactly how to follow your instructions, but it's exciting to think I could have a working Linux machine without reinstalling it.

Comment: I tried to add some clarity to my instructions, I think you can fix this without re-installing.

Comment: Okay thanks so much, I will try your suggestions out & get back to you!

Comment: Okay I found the black and white log in screen and it looks like I'm trying to log in to Ubuntu 12.04.4 LTS. I've tried "everything" I thought my log in / password might have been (bad habit but I have different passwords and just go by memory on everything). I can't log in b/c I forget my username / password combination.